# Declaring a common variable in a header gives linker error

Tags: c++

I have a variable in a file called "external.h"

This header file has header guards in it so that a variable isn't defined multiple times. and that other cpp files can use the variable.
This is what it looks like

File : External.h

```
#ifndef EXTERNAL_COMN_GUARD
#define EXTERNAL_COMN_GUARD
    char* rst = "SomeString";
#endif
```

Now when I attempt to build my project I get the following linker errors because of this:

```
1>contact.obj : error LNK2005: "char * rst" (?rst@@3PADA) already defined in peopleWidget.obj
1>moc_houses.obj : error LNK2005: "char * rst" (?rst@@3PADA) already defined in peopleWidget.obj
1>moc_messages.obj : error LNK2005: "char * rst" (?rst@@3PADA) already defined in peopleWidget.obj
1>huts_messages.obj : error LNK2005: "char * rst" (?rst@@3PADA) already defined in peopleWidget.obj
1>main_messages.obj : error LNK2005: "char * rst" (?rst@@3PADA) already defined in peopleWidget.obj
1>host.obj : error LNK2005: "char * rst" (?rst@@3PADA) already defined in peopleWidget.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "char * rst" (?rst@@3PADA) already defined in peopleWidget.obj
```

I resolved this problem by doing

const char rst[]  = "Something" ;

I wanted to know why this works and not `std::string rst = "something"`

Comment: "This header file has header guards in it so that a variable isn't defined multiple times." - it is. It is defined in each file that uses the header. Just like it is defined in each file in the case of everybody else who has made the mistake and posted yet another duplicate question lacking research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* rst = "SomeString";
```

declares and **defines** variable `rst` with global linkage visibility. Each time you include *External.h* you get another definition of `rst`. When time comes to link application, linker discovers multiple `rst` definitions and has no clue how to use them.

If you want to have `rst` shared among multiple sources, please split it's definition and declaration, or declare it static:

```
extern char* rst; // declaration in header
char* rst = "SomeString"; // definition in only one source file!
```

or

```
static char* rst = "SomeString";
```